dns servers and dns domain configuration issues in terraform
I am having issues with dns server list and domain configuration issues using provider vsphere v2.9.3 in terraform.
In my terraform.tfvars files, I have tried all of the below configs and none of them work when the vm gets created. during the plan stage it looks fine but when I look in /etc/resolv.conf file in the server, it's empty.
for the dns servers, I have tried:
vm_dns_servers_list = ["1.2.3.4", "1.2.3.5", "1.2.3.6"]

vm_dns_server = ["1.2.3.4", "1.2.3.5", "1.2.3.6"]

for the dns domain, I have tried:
vm_dns_suffix_list = "example.com"

vm_domain = "example.com"

none of them work.

I found that if I move the vm_dns_server(list) out of the linux_options but within the customize in main.tf then the ip's get tagged in /etc/resolv.conf.  Still trying to figure out why example.com is not getting tagged.
